# Regex for skipping specified URL extensions

Tags: regex

I have a link. Ex: http://my.domain/url.jsp

My goal is create patter that will be not allow any URLs with extension like this: `.ex1, .ex2, .ex3`

I was searching a long of time and find some approach, but it's really opposite that I want.

```
([^\s]+(\.(?i)(ex1|ex2|ex3))$)
```

Comment: What regex engine are you using?

Comment: If you need ANY ex# to be ignored, you need to state this in your question.  We *can* resolve that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If lookbehind is supported then this regex should work:

```
^\S+$(?<!\.(?:ex1|ex2|ex3)$)
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/gQDxYdDKcU

**If lookbehind isn't supported (e.g. Javascript) then use this lookahead based regex:**

```
^(?!.*?\.(?:ex1|ex2|ex3)$)\S+$
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/S0FGAETLr2

Comment: You had correct syntax before I did.  I deleted my answer.  +1

Comment: Thanks for help. This is really work, but when I try it with .ex11 is matches too:( I guess it will be simply different extension.

Comment: `.*` should probably be `\S+`.

Comment: @arshajii: Yes, sure `\S+` will be better.

Comment: @fashuser: Your URL is: `http://my.domain/url.ex11` which doesn't have extension of `ex1|ex2|ex3`. As per your question you wrote: `URLs with extension like this: .ex1, .ex2, .ex3`

Comment: Let me know if you want to block any `\.ex\d+`

Comment: Sorry it's work perfect. Thanks a lot! I was confusing a little bit :)